# How to implement a touch controller wake up circuit?

Tags: lcd, interrupts, touchscreen

I have an system-on-module (SoM) connected to an LCD with touchscreen interface. The SoM allows wake up from sleep by toggling one of its GPIOs. These are the datasheets: [LCD](https://docs.toradex.com/104497-7-inch-parallel-capacitive-touch-display-800x480-datasheet.pdf), [touch controller](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/mXT1066T2_1v2_Datasheet_EX.pdf) and [SoM](https://docs.toradex.com/104446-colibri-arm-som-imx6ull-datasheet.pdf).

I want to wake up the SoM when pressing the touchscreen. In this case, an interrupt should be generated on the touch controller's !CHG line (or !INT line of the LCD's interface). This interrupt is already routed to one of the SoM's pins, but I cannot use it as a wake up interrupt source because I did not find out how to configure the Linux device tree properly.

So a solution is to connect the !INT line to another GPIO (in parallel with the existing connection) and setting that GPIO as a input and wake up source.

I've tried connecting the !INT line to a GPIO configured as a wake up source in the device tree using gpio-keys (I've tested it using a push button and confirm that the pin works), but the SoM did not wake up.

So, does anybody know how to use the !INT line to wake up the SoM? Maybe the touch controller's interrupt duration is too small (a monostable multivibrator could prove useful in this case).

Comment: Perhaps you are just missing a pullup on the line, or the input is not properly configured. Add a schematic of the pushbutton that was working, and of the !INT line that is not working.

Comment: @VladimirCravero Hi. I have measured and confirm that a 5.6kohm pullup is present on the !INT line (maybe it is located on the LCD's PCB). This is the push button schematic: https://ibb.co/1XBpyBr . For testing, I have desoldered R2 and connected the touch controller's !INT line to C6. The GENERAL_BTN line goes to one of the SoC's GPIOs (configured as a wake up source).